# How do I import an csv/txt file into a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv

I have a project where I will be using a large amount of dummy data and I'll be doing things with it. I have a csv file in the assets folder that contains this data. There are 200+ lines of data. I only need to read it, I don't need to write to the file.

I need to read the file and then eventually parse each line into a class and then put that into a map. The parsing and putting it into a map isn't related to my issue though.

I am using Angular 17.1.3. I don't have an app.module.ts file as I'm in standalone mode (this was mentioned many times in fixes). Nothing else has been imported into the project. This is a brand new project.

---

I tried using httpClient but I got issues surrounding it not being provided:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from './company';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IDirectoryService } from './directory.service.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DirectoryService implements IDirectoryService{
  directory = new Map();
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){
      const fileName = "testData.csv";    
      this.http.get('assets/'+fileName, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }

    public getCompany(id:string):Company{
      return this.directory.get(id);
    }

    public getCount():Number{
      return this.directory.size;
    }
}
```

```
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_DirectoryService -> _DirectoryService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
```

I then tried just importing the file as an import but:

```
import * as data from '../../../assets/testData.csv';
```

```
Cannot find module '../../../assets/testData.csv' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I'm just trying to import a simple csv file. Something this simple can't be this hard right? I can convert it to txt if it would be easier.

I followed a couple tutorials online. I then ran into errors and then I googled the errors but most of them mention an app.module.ts file which seemly went away in later versions of Angular. Whenever I looked for solutions they were either for older versions or the author had some unrelated issue that was holding them back thus were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `provideHttpClient` to the environment providers, this will solve your issue!

```
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...

...
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    ...
    provideHttpClient(),
    ...
  ]
});
```

Comment: Where is the "environment providers"? I tried putting it both in the service and the app.component.ts but both gave errors. Also where exactly am I putting this?

app.components.ts = "RuntimeError: NG0906: The _DirectoryService is not an Angular component, make sure it has the `@Component` decorator."

my service = "ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: @PK-Mar my mistake will give more detailed answer next time!

Comment: I figured it out. Its the main.ts file that contains the providers but then they're definied in the app.config.ts. I've set this answer as the answer but I've also provided my own further down as I'm unable to add code styling to comments.

Answer (score 1):

I used Naren Murali's answer as a base as I had to do some further investigation due to some confusion on where exactly I was putting it. I'm providing my own answer as it needs some further clarification.

The "providers" according to the documentation (https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup#providing-httpclient-through-dependency-injection) were in the "main.ts" but then properly defined in the "app.config.ts" file.

I simply added the "provideHttpClient" in this file:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ]
};
```

This resolved my issue.